# Android Class Cast Exception inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, fragment, classcastexception

current I'm facing a problem which I cannot solve, I have a controller, a fragment, and an Activity, the problem is, I need the application context inside the controller, so I created an instance of the controller from the Fragment, and passed the appContext as an argument in its constructor, but an exception is thrown which is class cast exception in function getReligions() inside my controller at the line where I have a call back, any ideas how to solve this? 
Here is my code

```
      @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        controller = new Controller(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        imageUploadHandler = new ImageHandler(getApplicationContext());
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setup_edit_profile, container, false);
    }   

public void getReligions() {
    if (religions != null) {
        religionSpinner();
        return;
    }
    controller.getReligions();
}
```

In the controller class

```
public void getReligions(){
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        String url = "https://www.doyousonder.com/api/1.0.0/religion";
        queue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, url, params,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        ((GeneralCallBack)context).VolleyResponse(response,"Religions");
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Authorization", orientation_adj.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.bearer));
                return params;
            }
        });
    }
```

myLogCat:

```
     java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.eseed.sonder.utils.orientation_adj cannot be cast to 
    com.eseed.sonder.utils.GeneralCallBack
                                                                      at com.eseed.sonder.utils.Controller$61.onResponse(Controller.java:904)
                                                                      at com.eseed.sonder.utils.Controller$61.onResponse(Controller.java:902)
                                                                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
                                                                      at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here're my callbacks

```
     @Override
    public void VolleyResponse(String data) {

    }

    @Override
    public void VolleyResponse(JSONObject response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void VolleyResponse(JSONObject response, String data) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        if(data.equals("Religions")){
            try {
                Type t = new TypeToken<ReligionData[]>() {}.getType();
                religions = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("list_of_religions")), t);
                religion_names = new String[religions.length + 1];
                religion_names[0] = "Select";
                for (int i = 0; i < religions.length; i++) {
                    religion_names[i + 1] = (religions[i].religion_name);
                }
                religionSpinner();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(data.equals("Nationalities")){
            try {
                Type t = new TypeToken<NationalityData[]>() {
                }.getType();
                nationalities = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("list_of_nationalities")), t);
                nationality_names = new String[nationalities.length + 1];
                nationality_names[0] = "Select";
                for (int i = 0; i < nationalities.length; i++) {
                    nationality_names[i + 1] = (nationalities[i].nationality_name);
                }
                nationalitySpinner();
                loadingIcon.hide();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
```

`public class orientation_adj extends Application  {

```
private static Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    mContext = this;
    // register to be informed of activities starting up
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity,
                                      Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // new activity created; force its orientation to portrait
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

        }
    });
}
public static Context getContext(){
    return mContext;
}
```

}

Comment: Please add your logcat

Comment: @cricket_007 here is my logcat

Comment: Make your class `com.eseed.sonder.utils.orientation_adj` to extend or implement `GeneralCallback`

Comment: We cannot see how you defined `context`, and you've not used the `controller` anywhere here. Are you sure that the callback is used correctly?

Comment: @cricket_007 I declared my controller at the first line, I will add the callback but yes they're correct

Comment: You initialize the controller, but never use it for the code you show. Therefore, this isn't a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 I added it

Comment: Again, the error is very clear, but you really should post a MCVE. You still have not shown us the `orientation_adj`, where the actual problem exists

Comment: Note that Activities are already context objects. Why aren't you using `new Controller(getActivity());`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried it, but it did not execute the callback, however it did not crash

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
class orientation_adj extends Application
```

And here

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    controller = new Controller(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Your Application class isn't the context that implemented the interface, I assume the Activity is

In that case, you only need

```
controller = new Controller(getActivity());
```

After that, set up some additional log statements and breakpoints to debug the callback code better

Comment: Callback code is not executed, I added a Log at the first line, but it's not printed

Comment: Then your empty body of Volley onErrorResponse is probably executed

Comment: Did you even try that URL in the browser? I get `401 unauthorized`

Comment: I got the problem now, I have a callback in my activity as well as the Fragment, it executes the callback in the activity which has an empty body,so what should I do?

Comment: Glad to hear. You could also add a callback parameter to the Controller constructor. It does not need to be implemented on a Context class

Comment: But how can I force the code to execute the callback in the fragment not the activity?

Comment: You can't by casting the context. A Fragment is not a Context. You must give whatever class implemented that callback to your Controller